# English Translation of Pierre Cartier's thesis

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, translation

Question is as in the title:

Can some one point me (if there is any) to an English translation of Pierre Cartier's PhD thesis?

Comment: Perhaps you can just ask him: cartier?ihes.fr

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Sir, thanks for the response.. I am afraid my email might go unnoticed as he might get so many emails.. :) :) So, asked here...

Comment: By the way, several translations are mentioned in his publications list <http://www.ihes.fr/~cartier/REFERENCES/publications.html>, but not for his thesis.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly thanks you sir. I will see...